# Change label in a jQuery mobile's fieldcontain via css

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

In my jQuery mobile app I have a following element

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
 <label for="password">PIN:</label>
 <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" data-clear-btn="true"/>
</div>
```

What I'd like to do is to change 'PIN:'s font size. Unfortunately,

```
label[for=password] 
{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:32px  
}
```

didn't work for me. What can I try next?

Comment: also try using the !important tag to override the jquery mobile css default

Comment: its working http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/c49Fk/ tested on chrome desktop and safari mobile. or you can do it `$("[for=password]").css("font-size", "32px");`.

Comment: @Omar I need to do it via css. Thanks anyway!

Comment: !important doesn't work, either! I really do not know what am I doing wrong... Thank you guys, anyway!

Comment: I found out, that if I put the "label[..]" expression outside of my @media query it suddenly works. Inside "@media screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (orientation:portrait)" it doesn't work. Could someone explain me, why? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I saw at the wrong place. Works perfectly!